Excel column sort only showing row 1
I have an Excel spreadsheet And I'm trying to sort by the first column. When I click on the down arrow to identify my search criterion, It only shows data in the first row. All other columns in the spreadsheet are behaving the same way, only showing row one results as an option to select. I have a second workbook with the same column headings, and it is functioning normally.
Can you tell me how to copy and paste those column headings onto the malfunctioning workbook?  I tried virtually every option available and none worked.
Or, is there a way I can get the column sort function to read all the rows in the spreadsheet? I THINK This version of Excel is through Microsoft 365.Thank you for any help you can provide.

I figured it out. Thank you anyway.

Great. It'd be best if you can answer your own question and Accept it as Answer, so that the solutions remains for others to see.
